# Select all columns with distinct values from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains these columns
ID, NAME, JOB
what I want is to select one record of every distinct job in the table

from this table

```
ID NAME JOB
1  Juan  Janitor
2  Jun   Waiter
3  Jani  Janitor
4  Jeni  Bartender
```

to something like this

```
ID NAME JOB
1  Juan Janitor
2  Jun  Waiter
4  Jeni Bartender
```

Using distinct will allow me to select one distinct column but i want to select every column in the table, any one have an idea how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this

```
SELECT ID, NAME,JOB FROM
(
SELECT ID, NAME,JOB,Row_Number() Over (Partition BY NAME Order By ID) AS RN FROM `table1`
) AS T

WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN(ID), NAME, JOB FROM `table`
Group by NAME, JOB
```

Answer (score 0):

-- Fetch Only Rnk =1 Record to get desired output

```
SELECT ID,Rank() Over(Partition By Job Order By ID) As Rnk, Name,JOB
From EMP
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, NAME,JOB FROM
(
    SELECT ID,Rank() Over(Partition By Job Order By ID) As jobRank, Name,JOB from #abhi
) AS TTable

WHERE jobRank = 1
```